# FFmpeg stops encoding images to video after it encounters a bad image file

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, video

I am using a Raspberry Pi to record from 2 cameras at the same time using a multiplexer, meaning I can't set it to record mp4s directly and instead I have to take images, switch camera and then take another image and afterwards convert them to mp4s. Occasionally it'll take a bad jpg that's corrupted and isn't readable, I have tried to find a fix for this but I can't seem to find a way to take pictures consistently and a skipped frame isn't the end of the world anyway.

The problem is that when I use FFmpeg to convert these images to a video, the bad frame causes it to stop prematurely right before the frame. It doesn't error, it just stops. It would be perfect if there's a flag for it to skip the bad frame and continue encoding the rest of the video.

I've tried using:
-err_detect aggressive
-fflags discardcorrupt
Changing input and output frame rates

Here's the command I'm using:
`ffmpeg -framerate 1 -err_detect aggressive -fflags discardcorrupt -i recordings/current-recording/CameraA/%05d.jpg CameraA.mp4`

Here's what it makes in the console:

````
  Duration: 00:00:33.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 800x600, 1 fps, 1 tbr, 1 tbn, 1 tbc
File 'CameraA.mp4' already exists. Overwrite? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0xc0bac0] using cpu capabilities: ARMv6 NEON
[libx264 @ 0xc0bac0] profile High, level 3.1, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0xc0bac0] 264 - core 160 r3011 cde9a93 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2020 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=1 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'CameraA.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc), 800x600, q=-1--1, 1 fps, 16384 tbn, 1 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
frame=    5 fps=2.3 q=-1.0 Lsize=     252kB time=00:00:02.00 bitrate=1030.5kbits/s speed=0.94x    
video:251kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.350933%
[libx264 @ 0xc0bac0] frame I:1     Avg QP:15.01  size: 57504
[libx264 @ 0xc0bac0] frame P:1     Avg QP:15.04  size: 50197
[libx264 @ 0xc0bac0] frame B:3     Avg QP:14.46  size: 49452
[libx264 @ 0xc0bac0] consecutive B-frames: 20.0%  0.0%  0.0% 80.0%
[libx264 @ 0xc0bac0] mb I  I16..4:  0.1% 99.3%  0.6%
[libx264 @ 0xc0bac0] mb P  I16..4:  0.1% 91.8%  0.4%  P16..4:  3.3%  2.6%  1.9%  0.0%  0.0%    skip: 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0xc0bac0] mb B  I16..4:  0.0% 53.5%  2.9%  B16..8: 12.6% 11.7%  3.6%  direct:15.2%  skip: 0.3%  L0:17.2% L1:27.6% BI:55.2%
[libx264 @ 0xc0bac0] 8x8 transform intra:97.2% inter:92.9%
[libx264 @ 0xc0bac0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 99.3% 44.5% 10.2% inter: 97.7% 87.9% 7.1%
[libx264 @ 0xc0bac0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 50%  0% 50%  0%
[libx264 @ 0xc0bac0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 16% 17% 35%  4%  3%  4%  5%  6%  9%
[libx264 @ 0xc0bac0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 17% 14% 17%  9%  8%  7%  9% 10% 11%
[libx264 @ 0xc0bac0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 44% 30% 22%  4%
[libx264 @ 0xc0bac0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0xc0bac0] ref B L0: 85.9% 14.1%
[libx264 @ 0xc0bac0] ref B L1: 78.5% 21.5%
[libx264 @ 0xc0bac0] kb/s:409.69```
````

Comment: Corrupt images are fine. It will fail on 0 sized or missing  files. Overwrite these with the previous image.